# as3 access VARIABLE in parent MovieClip or Loader?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, global-variables, scope

Here is my code below. Its simple. I just need to get the var defined on the Main Stage and have every external swf get access to that var.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

IN MAIN SWF:

```
var ThePath:String;
ThePath = "happy/go/lucky/";
```

/// Below the code is in A LOADED SWF from the Main previous timeline above. (now showing full code to do this here)

```
var myMC:MovieClip;
myMC= parent as MovieClip;

trace("Your VAR PATH IS " + myMC.ThePath); /// DOES NOT WORK.
```

Thanks happy stackers!

**UPDATE 4-31-12**

IN SHORT: I need to make a global var in the main stage and allow all others externally loaded swf's access to that var.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.parent.parent);
myMC.ThePath
```

You should use camelCase as variable definitions.

**EDIT:**

Another solution is to pass a reference to the parent in the child swf when you load it in the loader (by setting a value, setting the reference) and then the child can reference the parent.

i.e.:

**Parent:**

function startLoad()
{
    var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(“Child.swf”);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    mLoader.load(mRequest);
}

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
{
    var childMC:MovieClip = loadEvent.currentTarget.content;
    addChild(childMC:MovieClip);
    childMC.refToMainSWF = this;
}

**For reference:**
http://genaboo.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/as2_vs_as3_root_parent_communicating_between_swfs/

Comment: If you found an answer, then please post it as an answer.  This will help out others in the same situation. Thanks.

Comment: My work around was not a very good work around. I still would love to know the answer to this question. My method turned out in the end to not work. I need to make a global var in the main stage and allow all others externally loaded swf's access to that var.

Comment: @iND Are you saying if I found an answer? I posted an answer basically, to reference the parent of the parent of the "child" movieclip to get access to the value. Honestly, the global var that Papa De Beau is a solid option. Children shouldn't know about their parents, though.

Comment: @DominicTancredi I think a comment got deleted somewhere along the way.  I was actually asking the OP to post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
trace("Your VAR PATH IS " + root.ThePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with static properties (variables), importing that as needed for global access. See [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783017/as3-static-class-versus-singleton).