# Syntax Of Static Constructor in Actionscript-3?

Tags: actionscript-3, static, constructor

How do I define a static constructor that is run when class is initialized ?

I can't get it right:

```
// version a:
{}

// version b:
static {}

// version c:
static function Foo()
{}

// version d:
static ()
{}

// version e:
()
{}

// version f:
static function Foo():void
{}
```

Comment: this will help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783017/as3-static-class-versus-singleton

Comment: Sorry no, there was not 1 static constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Found it out:

```
public class Test
{
    public function Test()
    {
        trace("normal constructor");
    }

    // static constructor (version a)
    {
        trace("static constructor");
    }
}
```

For some reason no question was asked about static constructor in AS-3 ?

---

[Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180785/dave) suggested, I checked: Actionscript initializers don't even need any syntax:

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{
    trace("hello world");

    public function Test()
    {
        trace("constructor");
    }

    trace("bye world");
}
```

Comment: It has been asked before elsewhere on the internet; http://manishjethani.com/archives/2008/03/31/static-initializers-in-as3 And I think it's likely (but I can't be sure) that the braces are just for scoping; you could do without them.